# Python. Отслеживание частоты запросов к серверу по ip

Tags: python, django, ооп, request

Задача создать сервис, который будет отслеживать количество запросов к серверу по ip-адресу. В случае превышения определенного количества запросов за определенное время,  сервис должен выдавать код 429. В моем коде для выполнения данной задачи применяются глобальные переменные: TIME - время с момента первого запроса, в течении которого проводится счет количества запросов, MAX_REQ - максимально допустимое число запросов за указанное время и список IP_LIST, в котором содержится словарь, который в свою очередь содержит ip, количество запросов (count) и время первого запроса. Реализован с использованием Django. Данный код добавляет в список словарь, считает количество запросов, выдает код 429, в случае превышения допустимого числа, по истечению указанного времени удаляет словарь с ip из списка, и затем должен добавлять очередной ip. Но на этом моменте код не работает так как планировалось, после удаления словаря из списка новый словарь не добавляется.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import time

IP_LIST = []
TIME = 20
MAX_REQ = 25

def count_ip(request, ip):
    _ip = next((el for el in IP_LIST if el['ip'] == ip), False)
    if _ip:
        time_now = time.time()
        if time_now - _ip['time'] > TIME:
            new_list = [el for el in IP_LIST if not el == _ip]
            return new_list
        else:
            _ip['count'] += 1
            if _ip['count'] >= MAX_REQ:
                return render(request, 'index.html', status=429)
            return IP_LIST
    else:
        now = time.time()
        IP_LIST.append({'ip': ip, 'count': 1, 'time': now})
    return IP_LIST

def get_client_ip(req):
    """
    This is used to get the user's IP from the request object.

    """
    x_forwarded_for = req.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
    if x_forwarded_for:
        ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
    else:
        ip = req.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR', "unknown")
    return ip


def index(request):
    ip = get_client_ip(request)
    IP_LIST = count_ip(request, ip)
    return render(request, 'index.html', context={
        'ip': IP_LIST,
    })
```

index.html

```
<h1>IP: {{ ip }}</h1>
```

Comment: что значит "не добавляется", падает с ошибкой?

Comment: Остается лишь пустой список. Ошибок не возникает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

не надо тебе стейта в рантайме. это будет работать только пока ты используешь сервер разработки `manage.py run`. как только ты перейдешь на продакшен окружение, то это перестанет работать сразу же. храни подобного рода стейт в редисе.

тем более что доступ к редису очень быстр, в редисе уже реализован механизм удаления по таймауту.

```
_ip = next((el for el in IP_LIST if el['ip'] == ip), False)
```

очень долгая штука. храни не список словарей, а словарь словарей, чтобы по ip сразу брать данные.

С редисом выглядеть будет примерно так

```
from redis import Redis


def check_raite_limit(remote_addr):
    time = time.time()
    redis = Redis.from_url("redis://localhost:6379")
    data = json.loads(redis.get(remote_addr) or b'{"count": 0, "time":  null}')
    # any logic
    redis.set(remote_addr, json.dumps(data), ex=5)  # 5 seconds
    return True  # или False, смотря как ты там посчитаешь
```

Comment: Благодарю. Redis помог выполнить данные задачи.